# Auto populate combobox

Tags: javascript, html

IN my case i want to implement multi select auto complete combobox using html,javascript.

Is there any body who knows how to implement it.

Which will be similar to text field shown in stackoverflow while adding multipal tags to any question.

Comment: I'm sure plenty of people know how to do what you want. However, you will need to ask a more focused question and provide some more background details of the problem if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about multiple drop down boxes that are linked, so that the selection in the first drop down menu determines the possibilities in the next, then the [ASP.NET Toolkit has a nice cascading drop down sample](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx). This will only, of course, come in handy if you are programming in ASP.NET. I would not recommend trying to reverse engineer the solution.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by auto populate?
If you want to populate the drop down box dynamically you can just use a normal HTML Select tag and use Ajax to fetch the list of values to be shown in the drop down